# What function could do that? (again)

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Here is a reformulated question: Can one show a real function $f$ (whose domain is the set of all pairs of reals for which $x\lt y$) such that

- $x \lt f(x,y)\lt y$,
- $f(a,b) \le f(c,d)$ iff $a \lt f(c,d)$ and $f(a,b) \lt d$ ?

Comment: This smells a lot like Baire category theorem somehow

Comment: This is only Bare intuition.

Comment: But Hmmm, I sort of know what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Von Eitzen's reference to the Baire category theorem helped me solve my problem. But I have only a strange explanation as to how. In the proof of the said theorem there are five words in this order:  $$...the\  first\  index\ for\ which...$$ These five words suggested to me the olfactory solution.

Now let's construct the desired function the following way: Let $r_1,r_2,...$  be an arbitrary listing of the rational numbers. The definition of my function is then
$$f(x,y)=r_i $$ if $i$ is $$the\  first\  index\ for\ which$$ $r_i$ is in $(x,y)$. Checking that the conditions are met is easy now. Obviously there are plenty of such functions.

My next question is if von Eitzen knew the solution when pointing to the Baire theorem(s)?